# How to get principal in reactive Spring controller, without adding some Principal to the method signature?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I have a reactive Spring Boot controller using OAuth2 security via introspection. And if I try something like this in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ebox2",
        produces = {"application/json"},
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Ebox>> getEBoxById2(BearerTokenAuthentication authentication, @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal,
        Principal user) {
    //Here I can access all the principals in the method params
    return result;
}
```

Here I can correctly access the Principal object.

But my spring controller is implementing a generated interface.
So I can't add "BearerTokenAuthentication authentication", or "@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal" to my controller method signature.

But I do need to get a hold of the principal somehow, to do a DB lookup based on something inside the principal.

E.g.

```
@Override
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Ebox>> getEBoxById(ServerWebExchange exchange) {

    userRepository.getByPrincipalName(/*here I need a property inside the Principal*/);

}
```

The repository is blocking (no R2DBC yet). So how can I get the principal in the controller? (e.g. pull it out of the exchange) I tried with blocking, but that doesn't seem to work, as it resolves to null.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards,

Jochen

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<EBox>> getEBoxById2() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            // continue
}
```

In your case, the `Authentication` should be of time `BearerTokenAuthentication` and should contain a `OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal` in `Authentication#getPrincipal`.

Comment: Any reason why this always returns null in my application? Is there any extra config required?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that `SecurityContext#getAuthentication` is null? It may be because you are not authenticated. Without seeing more code, it's also hard to diagnose. Would recommend you ask your own separate question.